# How to select custom template on site collection creation

Tags: rest, sharepoint-on-prem, site-template, custom, site-creation

I'm trying to create a new site collection in sharepoint 2019 with the api `_api/SPSiteManager/create`. The only template i can choose are `STS#3` and `SITEPUBLISHING#0`. If I choose any other template it will tell me :

> "Performing this operation on a site with this template is not
> allowed."

Is there a way to create a new site collection with a custom template via api?

Comment: How you have created custom template ? it's using Site Definition concept (Farm Solution) or you are using Web Template (using Sandbox solution)?

Comment: I have an exported custom template that is a WebTemplate, it's a .wsp file.

Comment: How you are using API? I meant using C# code or using any other approach?

Comment: I'am using curl and javascript

Comment: I've managed to create a sitecollection with a custom Template, for everyone interested:
this can't be done via client side api but only from the server side. I've created a Console Application in Visual Studio with this code: [link](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/)